# How to hide the lines behind the surface in Mayavi in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, mayavi, maya-api, mayavi.mlab

I am trying to create a sphere with lines and dots on it. But since I am plotting the sphere, the lines and the points separately in the code, I don't think Mayavi recognized it as a whole figure. So the lines and points on the rear face of the sphere are also visible. Is there a way to make the whole scene opaque and show only one plane at a time? (Opacity only makes the individual element i.e. sphere or line or point opaque; not the whole figure.)

This is what I am getting now:

[image]

This is what I want it to look like. As I rotate this sphere, it should only show the points on the surface that is facing us.

[image]